# How create NSLayoutConstraint when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I have `UITableView` on SingleView. Table view have constraint left 0, right 0, bottom 0, top 520. I need change top 520 to  the 0 when scrolling up, and when scrolling bottom return 520. How can make it. 
How change `NSLayoutConstraint` from scroll in -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

I was trying to implement the so-but failed

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if (scrollView.tag == 1){

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < pointNow.y) {

            self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 0;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }];

        }else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > pointNow.y) {

            self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 520;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an outlet of TopSpace constraint and change its constant value in scrollView delegates as you want.

Comment: Instead, track the scrolling in your `willDisplayCell` or `CellForRowAtIndexPath` delegates with indexPath and perform appropriate actions based on row or section

Comment: @NSNoob UITableView inherit from UIScrollView

Comment: This means that delegate methods of UIScollView should work

Comment: @NSNoob scrollView parent tableview and i think implement this.

Comment: @Andrei Trotsky did `scrollViewDidScroll` method call? if not check that you `self.tableView.delegate = self;`

Comment: and check that you declare `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` in interface extension

Comment: how to implement it? its real? this code work but only scroll up if contentOffset.y > 0

Comment: @iSashok tableView delegate

Answer (score 2):

Replace `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` in your code by-- `[_tableView beginUpdates];` and `[_tableView endUpdates];`. Also modify your variable pointNow as follows.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (UIScrollViewDelegate){

}


@end

@implementation ViewController
CGPoint pointNow;

- (void)viewDidLoad{

     [super viewDidLoad];   
     pointNow = CGPointMake(0, 0);

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{



        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < pointNow.y) {

            self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 0;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [_tableView beginUpdates];
                [_tableView endUpdates];
            }];

        }else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > pointNow.y) {

            self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 520;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [_tableView beginUpdates];
                [_tableView endUpdates];
            }];
        }
    pointNow = scrollView.contentOffset;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the setNeedsUpdateConstraints method right after you change the constraint constant. Like:

```
[self.tableView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

**Update -**

If I understood you correctly, this is what you are looking for I think :

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{

    if(self.heightLogTabTableView.contentOffset.y<0){
        //it means table view is pulled down like refresh
    }
    else if(self.heightLogTabTableView.contentOffset.y >= 0) {
        //it means table view is being scrolled up
    }    
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I see the logic, I need to coordinate global variable default, and coordinate with the scrolls, the method should compare the present with the previous coordinate with scrolls and determine where to go if you scroll up to change something constraint to 0 if the return down coordinate default. There idea how to implement it in this method?

Answer (score 0):

This single line of code will solve your issue with all `top,bottom,left, right` constraints to `Zero`

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(520, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: i add this code in  (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView but its not work

Comment: add it in -viewdidload() and no need to implement -scrollViewDidScroll:()

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and it will help you....

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    if (scrollView.tag != 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(self.heightLogTabTableView.contentOffset.y<0)
    {
        self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 0;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }];
    }
    else 
    {
        self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 520;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i add global varible CGFloat in my `.h` file `"@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lastScrollOffset;"`

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if (scrollView.tag == 1){


        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > _lastScrollOffset) {

            self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = 0;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }];
        } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < _lastScrollOffset) {

            self.heightLogTabTableView.constant = self.informationTask.frame.size.height;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }];
        }

        _lastScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }

    else if (scrollView.tag == 2){

     if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > _lastScrollOffset) {

         self.heightCommentTabTableView.constant = 0;
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

             self.typeCommentView.hidden = NO;

         }];

     } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < _lastScrollOffset) {

         self.heightCommentTabTableView.constant = self.informationTask.frame.size.height + 220;

         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
             self.typeCommentView.hidden = YES;
         }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need compare my global varible in scroll.contentOffset.y.